# Can't create Magento custom admin module

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I've trying for many hours to create a custom admin module but no luck so far. Here's my code:

/app/code/local/CompanyName/MailView/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
   <CompanyName_MailView>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</CompanyName_MailView>
</modules>
<admin>
<routers>
    <adminhtml>       
       <!-- <use>admin</use>          -->
        <args>
            <modules>
                <mailview before="Mage_Adminhtml">CompanyName_MailView</mailview>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
</routers>
</admin>
<global>
<helpers>
    <companyname_mailview>
        <class>CompanyName_MailView_Helper</class>
    </companyname_mailview>
</helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/CompanyName/MailView/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<menu>
    <companyname translate="title" module="CompanyName_mailview">
        <title>View Emails</title>
        <sort_order>999</sort_order>
        <action>adminhtml/mailview/index</action>         
    </companyname>
</menu>
  <acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>                
                <CompanyName translate="title" module="companyname_mailview">
                    <title>Top Level Pulse Storm Menu Item</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                     <children>
                        <example>
                            <title>Example Menu Item</title>
                        </example>
                    </children>
                </CompanyName>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
  </config>
```

and here's my controller: app/code/local/CompanyName/MailView/controllers/MailViewController.php:

```
<?php
class CompanyName_MailView_MailViewController extends 
 Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
  {
      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

and my helper: app/code/local/CompanyName/MailView/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
 class CompanyName_MailView_Helper_Data extends 
 Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
 }
```

The module appears in the admin panel. When I click on it though I get an error 404 page not found.

I've been following [this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited/) tutorial but no luck so far. What am I missing here?  Thank you

Comment: Have you tried logging out and back in again on the admin after installing the module?

Comment: Yes.. in the following sequence: clear cache, log out, log in and clear cache again

Comment: It looks like you are missing  <adminhtml><layout><updates> in your config.xml, but calling the loadLayout and renderLayout in your controller.

Comment: what do I add exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few minor problems. Compare the files below with your xml to see the fixes.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CompanyName_MailView>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CompanyName_MailView>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <CompanyName_MailView before="Mage_Adminhtml">CompanyName_MailView_Adminhtml</CompanyName_MailView>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <companyname>
                <class>CompanyName_MailView_Helper</class>
            </companyname>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <companyname translate="title">
            <title>View Emails</title>
            <sort_order>999</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/mailview</action>
        </companyname>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <companyname translate="title">
                        <title>View Emails</title>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    </companyname>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Change the case on your mailview controller from `MailViewController.php` to `MailviewController.php`. Move it to a subfolder of `Adminhtml` so the full path will be: `app/code/local/CompanyName/MailView/controllers/Adminhtml/MailviewController.php`

```
<?php

class CompanyName_MailView_Adminhtml_MailviewController 
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction() {

        die('This admin controller works!');

        //$this->loadLayout();
        //$this->renderLayout();

    }

}
```

Make the above changes, flush cache, log out of admin then log back in and you will be able to click your View Mails link. The test in `MailviewController.php` will dump "This admin controller works!".  After you get this part working, look into adding layout overrides in your config.xml to continue building out your admin module.

Answer (score 0):

Your Helper class seems top be wrong. Please fix it first.

```
<?php
class Converge_MailView_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Also in config.xml. There is a Typo.

```
<helpers>
    <companyname_mailview>
        <class>CompanyName_MailView_Helper</class>
    </companyname_mailview>
</helpers>
```

Comment: sorry... that was a copy paste typo. Code is Ok and still shows the same  :-(

Comment: can you please tell me which URL you are try to access which gives you 404 error?

Comment: well... when I click on my new module I get this link  https://myWebSite/index.php/admin/admin/mailview/index/